# React native websocket working in debug mode but not after creating apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, websocket, laravel-echo

Please help. I am creating an app in react native that displays live data of orders, everything is working fine in debug mode when I run the app on the emulator or directly run it on my mobile, the WebSockets are working and data is displayed on the screen automatically. But when I create the APK of the project and install it, the data is not showing nor the web sockets are working please help.

I tried to configure network security but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

You can refer below screenshot:

[image]